# Can Android WebView.eveluateJavascript() lose data in Samsung note 9 device?

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, android-webview

I am seeing a weird issue while sending data from Java to Js inside webview(only on Note 9 device). I am passing JSON String every 2 second from Java to JS using eveluateJavascript() as shown in below code snippet.

```
private void sendResponse(final String responsePayload) {
    
    final String javaScript = "javascript:window:sendResponse('" + responsePayload + "')";

    wv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            wv.evaluateJavascript(javaScript, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String value) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

}` I
```

I am able to get the entire JSON response string in my JS method on note 8 device.
But on Note 9 device; for first couple of times I am receiving the entire JSON response string sent by Java, then for subsequent response I am receiving null for test1 and test2 array of objects in the JSON(Funny part is Java code is sending the entire response, by the time I receive it in JS it's losing the value).
JSON response:

[image: given is the JSON response I am passing]

Comment: try to step debug the issue adding a breakpoint

Comment: @rupps I found the whole scenario that java is sending a correct response but by the time it reached to JS, the values of said test1 and test2 arrays of objects are going null.